# Target null on jquery scroll

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, scroll

I have been trying to implement a scrolling script which will smoothly transition from the menu item name to the associated `a name` value.  Here is the script:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
    }
    }
    });
```

This is being implemented on a Joomla 3 site.  I have tested this script on a blank `php` script outside of the CMS and it seems to work fine.  The console error reads as `TypeError: target is null`

`target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying that its working on seprate page so, Have you check may be your jquery is conflicting !!! change your $ sign for joomla.

Hope can help for you !!

Comment: What do you mean by changing the $ sign for Joomla?

Comment: Ahh it works now... I changed `$` to `jQuery` and it is now good.  Thanks.

Comment: check with change your $ sign with jQuery.